# Customize checked items in ListView

Tags: android

I have a list view with black text items with single choice mode.
I would like the checked item to be red.
Is there any straightforward way to do this, or do I need to listen for item click callbacks, change the colors manually, etc.?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get any answers yet.

Comment: Refer this example http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multiple-options/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that will "automatically" change the background of an entire listview item based on a checkbox, so you'll pretty much have to handle the event.